# How to get new userinput in a stream while its running using Java8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I need to validate user input and if it doesn't meet the conditions then I need to replace it with correct input. So far I am stuck on two parts. Im fairly new to java8 and not so familiar with all the libraries so if you can give me advice on where to read up more on these I would appreciate it.

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList(args);
List<String> validatedinput = input.stream()
   .filter(p -> {
       if (p.matches("[0-9, /,]+")) {
           return true;
       }
       System.out.println("The value has to be positve number and not a character");
       //Does the new input actually get saved here?
       sc.nextLine();
       return false;
   }) //And here I am not really sure how to map the String object
   .map(String::)
   .validatedinput(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: your code makes little sense, what is `sc`? And also you are trying to change `validatedinput` with a `Stream`? this will obviously not work

Comment: @Eugene `Scanner`, just have a feeling what the OP is trying to do shouldn't be done with streams.

Comment: @Aominè are you into mind reading these days? :) it makes sense to be a scanner though...

Comment: @Eugene yes it is Scanner,

Comment: @Eugene I got your first respond before you deleted it, so thanks, also as I stated above I am new to this so ofcourse my code doesnt make sense, thats why I am here on this forum to get feedback and advice, your first reponse was more constructive than the second and I learned more from it, pity you deleted it

Comment: I can always un-delete it if it resolves your problem... the idea of the deletion was that I did not understood what you meant, so did not want to post something that I did not understand myself

Comment: @Eugene well then I guess we know who is the mind reader here, anyways problem solved

Comment: :) here you go, undeleted if that really helped u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of logic shouldn't be done with streams, a `while` loop would be a good candidate for it.

First, let's partition the data into two lists, one list representing the valid inputs and the other representing invalid inputs:

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> resultSet =
            Arrays.stream(args)
                    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.matches(yourRegex), 
                                 Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

Then create the while loop to ask the user to correct all their invalid inputs:

```
int i = 0;
List<String> invalidInputs = resultSet.get(false);
final int size = invalidInputs.size();    
while (i < size){
     System.out.println("The value --> " + invalidInputs.get(i) +
             " has to be positive number and not a character");
     String temp = sc.nextLine();
     if(temp.matches(yourRegex)){
         resultSet.get(true).add(temp);
         i++;
     }
}
```

Now, you can collect the list of all the valid inputs and do what you like with it:

```
List<String> result = resultSet.get(true);
```

Comment: The lists the collector produces by default, are not guaranteed to be mutable. So you need, `Collectors.partitioningBy(…, Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))` to be sure to have a list you can `add` to.

Comment: @Aominé I thought that streams were supposed to optimize the ever popular for/foreach loops so we dont have to do it. Also I kinda took it for granted that they would have added some method that actually can manipulate or edit the data while its being passed. Simply put,as far as I have understood streams work just in the same way an assembly line does in a car factory where you have different people(methods) working on the same line doing what needs to be done if the car matches the condition. So a method that allows some type of updating of value would be more practical. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Em.C this is too broad of a topic to discuss (streams), there are entire books written about it. however, a good place to start is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html then any specific topic you don't understand just search it on google and I am pretty sure there will be a lot of answer ;-)

Comment: @Em.C streams are not supposed to replace every for loop, they are a tool box for certain kinds of tasks for which you might have used loops in previous Java versions. But not for all kind of tasks. Your car assembly line is a good picture, actually. In such a car factory, a worker wouldn’t leave his place to ask a customer for missing specs or query the external supplier for additional parts, would he? The assembly line is for the bulk processing, management tasks or post-processing are done outside of it.

Comment: @Holger That makes sense, unless its the last worker, the terminal one at the end of the day before everything is about to get shipped,he would probably be able to "walk away". So technically a terminal method should be able to do the same?Maybe...

Comment: @Em.C depends on the terminal operation, e.g. `.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(…, function))` works exactly like that, the `function` will be applied after everything else has been done. Likewise, a terminal like `.findAny().orElseGet(supplier)` will apply the supplier after everything else, if no match was found (though technically, it’s not part of the stream operation anymore). There are things where it fits into the mental model, for others, stay with conventional code. After all, tools shall help you, so use whatever tool makes the task easiest…